# creating a complex login and registering system in Tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am creating a program in python 3.3, whiles using tkinter, which should register the user's personal information such as their email first and second name. so far the user can register themselves and their information will be saved in a file. However, there is an error. if the user has already created an account, when they enter their login details and click "submit", the program doesnt read the file and portrays nothing. therefore, i want the program to read if the user's details exist in the file or not.
Here is my code:

```
def init_screen(self):

    self.MainScreen.title("Sonico Services")

    self.MainScreen.configure(background = "#ffff00")        

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    RegisterButton = Button(self, text="Register", bg = "red", fg = "yellow",command=self.User_Register)

    RegisterButton.place(x=200,y=100)

    LoginButton=Button(self,text="Login",bg="red",fg="yellow",command=self.User_Login)

    LoginButton.place(x=270,y=100)

def User_Register(self):
    Firstname=Label(application,text="First Name: ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=30,column=7)
    Secondname=Label(application,text="Second Name: ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=30,column=10)
    Emailtag=Label(application,text="Email address: ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=15,column=7)
    Password=Label(application,text="Password : ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=35,column=7)
    SubmitButton=Button(self,text="Submit",bg="red",fg="yellow",command=self.File_Manipulation)
    SubmitButton.place(x=140,y=100)
    EntryBox1=Entry(application)
    EntryBox2=Entry(application)
    EntryBox3=Entry(application)
    EntryBox4=Entry(application)
    EntryBox1.grid(row=30,column=12)
    EntryBox2.grid(row=30,column=8)
    EntryBox3.grid(row=15,column=8)
    EntryBox4.grid(row=35,column=8)
    global EntryBox1
    global EntryBox2
    global EntryBox3
    global EntryBox4
def File_Manipulation(self):
    with open("Client Data.txt","w+")as client_file:
        EB=EntryBox1.get()
        EB2=EntryBox2.get()
        EB3=EntryBox3.get()
        EB4=EntryBox4.get()
        infocombo=EB +(",")+ EB2+(",")+EB3+(",")+EB4+("\n")
        client_file.write(infocombo)
def User_Login(self):
    Firstname=Label(application,text="First Name: ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=30,column=7)
    Password=Label(application,text="Password : ",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=35,column=7)
    EntryBox1=Entry(application)
    EntryBox4=Entry(application)
    EntryBox1.grid(row=30,column=8)
    EntryBox4.grid(row=35,column=8)
    SubmitButton=Button(self,text="Submit",bg="red",fg="yellow",command=self.Data)
    SubmitButton.place(x=140,y=100)
    EB4=EntryBox4.get()
    EB1=EntryBox1.get()
    global EB1
    global EB4
def Data(self):
    data=open("Client Data.txt","w+")
    read=data.readlines()
    for line in read:
        if (EB4+EB1) in line:
            WelcomeLabel=Label(application,text="Welcome! you have successfully logged in",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=30,column=10)
        else:
            ExitLabel=Label(application, text= "Your account does not exist, please register first",bg="yellow",fg="red").grid(row=30,column=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is read the file in to your program using `.readlines()` and check against the list something like the below:

```
if (email in list_of_lines) == False: #if it passes this statement then the account doesn't already exist so we need to create a new account.
    add_account()
```

Answer (score 0):

My code will help you to create a register program using tkinter where you can store all the customers data in notepad (ie) we are using notepad as our database:

```
from tkinter import *

def Register():
    global root
    user_entry=username.get()
    pass_entry=password.get()
    user_data=open(user_entry + ".txt", "w")
    user_data.write("Username: " + user_entry + "\n")
    user_data.write("Password: " + pass_entry)
    user_data.close()
    username.delete(0, END)
    password.delete(0, END)
    Label(text="Data saved!", fg="#b0bfb6", bg="#1f1e21").pack()

def start():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Register")
    root.geometry("400x300")
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.configure(bg="white")
    global username
    global password    
    Label(root, text="Username: ").pack()
    username=Entry(root, width=25)
    username.pack()
    Label(root, text="Password:").pack()
    password=Entry(root, width=25)
    password.pack()
    Button(root, text="Register", command=Register).pack()
    root.mainloop()
start()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).